# Unable to extract mailmerge fields from Word DOCX using PHP and DOM

Tags: php, xml, ms-word, docx

I'm trying to come up with a solution that will allow users to upload a mail merge-enabled Word DOCX template file.  Ideally, the system will read the DOCX file, extract the XML, find the mail merge fields and save them to a database for mapping down the road.  I may go with a SOAP service such as Zend LiveDocX or PHPDOCX or something else entirely -- but for now I need to figure out how to identify the fields in a DOCX file.  To do that I've started with this article: http://dfmaxwell.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/using-php-to-process-a-word-document-mail-merge/

I've adapted it a bit to my needs (which may be a problem, though I get the same error with the original code as well.)  Specifically I'm not using it to perform the mail merge at this time, I just want to identify the fields.  Here's what I've got:

```
    $newFile = '/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/template.docx';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if( $zip->open( $newFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CHECKCONS ) !== TRUE ) { echo 'failed to open template'; exit; }
    $file = 'word/document.xml';
    $data = $zip->getFromName( $file );
    $zip->close();

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML( $data );
    $wts = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main', 'fldChar');

    $mergefields = array();

    function getMailMerge(&$wts, $index) {
        $loop = true;
        $counter = $index;
        $startfield = false;
        while ($loop) {
            if ($wts->item($counter)->attributes->item(0)->nodeName == 'w:fldCharType') {
                $nodeName = '';
                $nodeValue = '';
                switch ($wts->item($counter)->attributes->item(0)->nodeValue) {
                    case 'begin':
                        if ($startfield) {
                            $counter = getMailMerge($wts, $counter);
                        }
                        $startfield = true;
                        if ($wts->item($counter)->parentNode->nextSibling) {
                            $nodeName = $wts->item($counter)->parentNode->nextSibling->childNodes->item(1)->nodeName;
                            $nodeValue = $wts->item($counter)->parentNode->nextSibling->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
                        }
                        else {
                            // No sibling
                            // check next node
                            $nodeName = $wts->item($counter + 1)->parentNode->previousSibling->childNodes->item(1)->nodeName;
                            $nodeValue = $wts->item($counter + 1)->parentNode->previousSibling->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
                        }
                        if (substr($nodeValue, 0, 11) == ' MERGEFIELD') {
                            $mergefields[] = strtolower(str_replace('"', '', trim(substr($nodeValue, 12))));
                        }
                        $counter++;
                    break;
                case 'separate':
                    $counter++;
                    break;
                case 'end':
                    if ($startfield) {
                        $startfield = false;
                    }
                    $loop = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $counter;
    }

    for ($x = 0; $x < $wts->length; $x++) {
        if ($wts->item($x)->attributes->item(0)->nodeName == 'w:fldCharType' && $wts->item($x)->attributes->item(0)->nodeValue == 'begin') {
            $newcount = getMailMerge($wts, $x);
            $x = $newcount;
        }
    }
```

I have no problem opening the DOCX file with ZipArchive() and if I use print_r($doc->saveHTML()); I see the XML data just fine.  The problem is that when I execute my code I get Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object pointing to this:

```
$nodeName = $wts->item($counter)->parentNode->nextSibling->childNodes->item(1)->nodeName;
```

Google has let me down when trying to figure out this error, can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: used the same script and found that it had to many ChildNodes.
    
    $nodeName = $wts->item($counter)->parentNode->nextSibling->nodeName;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution -- it's not quite as elegant as what I was hoping for but here goes.

Using xml_parser_create_ns I can search the DOCX file for the keys I need, specifically "HTTP://SCHEMAS.OPENXMLFORMATS.ORG/WORDPROCESSINGML/2006/MAIN:INSTRTEXT" which identifies all fields marked as "MERGEFIELD".  Then I can dump the results into an array and use them to update the database.  To wit:

```
    // Word file to be opened
    $newFile = '/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/template.docx';

    // Extract the document.xml file from the DOCX archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if( $zip->open( $newFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CHECKCONS ) !== TRUE ) { echo 'failed to open template'; exit; }
    $file = 'word/document.xml';
    $data = $zip->getFromName( $file );
    $zip->close();

    // Create the XML parser and create an array of the results
    $parser = xml_parser_create_ns();
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $data, $vals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    // Cycle the index array looking for the important key and save those items to another array
    foreach ($index as $key => $indexitem) {
        if ($key == 'HTTP://SCHEMAS.OPENXMLFORMATS.ORG/WORDPROCESSINGML/2006/MAIN:INSTRTEXT') {
            $found = $indexitem;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Cycle *that* array looking for "MERGEFIELD" and grab the field name to yet another array
    // Make sure to check for duplicates since fields may be re-used
    if ($found) {
        $mergefields = array();
        foreach ($found as $field) {
            if (!in_array(strtolower(trim(substr($vals[$field]['value'], 12))), $mergefields)) {
                $mergefields[] = strtolower(trim(substr($vals[$field]['value'], 12)));
            }
        }
    }

    // View the fruits of your labor
    print_r($mergefields);
```